# Firebase - How to create a new batch on the same batch reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using batches to migrate csv data to the firestore. The problem is that there is alot of data and the batch exceeds 500 ops limit so I have to commit current batch and make a new one in its place. Something like this:

```
function importRecord() {
   let records = [...]
   let batch = db.batch()
   for(let record in records) {
      createRecord(db, batch)
   }
   if(batch.ops.length !== 0) {
      batch.commit()
      batch = db.batch()
   }
}

function createRecord(db, batch) {
   if(batch.ops.length >= 500) {
      batch.commit()
      batch = db.batch()
   }
   batch.update(...)
   ...
}
```

Now when I create a new batch on the passed batch the batch in outer function loses reference.
How do I go around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define the function in the closure of `importRecord`:

```
function importRecord() {
   let records = [...]
   let batch = db.batch()

   createRecord = async (record) => {
      if(batch.ops.length >= 500) {
         batch.commit()
         batch = db.batch()
      }
      batch.update(...)
      ...
   }

   for(let record in records) {
      createRecord(record)
   }
   if(batch.ops.length !== 0) {
      batch.commit()
      batch = db.batch()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not move the logic around a bit, and then you don't have to worry about it?

```
async function importRecord() {
   let records = [...]
   let batch = db.batch()
   for(let record in records) {
      if (batch.ops.length >= 500) {
        await batch.commit();
        batch = db.batch();
      }
      createRecord(db, batch)
   }
   if(batch.ops.length > 0) {
      await batch.commit()
   }
}

function createRecord(db, batch) {
   batch.update(...)
}
```

Comment: The issue is I have multiple functions and loops inside createRecord function.